# What does "joint" mean in "International joint conference"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I noticed there are a few conferences that use the word *joint* in their name:

- International joint conference on artificial intelligence (IJCAI)
- Joint Conference on Digital Libraries (JCDL)
- International Joint Conference on Computational Intelligence (IJCCI)
- [many others](https://www.google.ch/search?q=joint+conference)

I thought *joint* means that there are at least two parties involved, like in the example:

> this is a joint venture between Company A and Company B.

But I cannot identify which are the multiple parties in these conferences. So what does *joint* mean in their title?

Comment: Have you done any research? For example, if you go to the IJCAI website, on the homepage it says "IJCAI consists of two divisions: the Conference Division and the AI Journal Division.". There's your 'joint'.

Comment: And, from the [JCDL websiite](http://www.jcdl.org/): _JCDL enhances the tradition of conference excellence already established by the ACM and IEEE-CS by combining the annual events that these professional societies have sponsored on an annual basis, the ACM Digital Libraries Conferences and the IEEE-CS Advances in Digital Libraries Conferences._ So, a joint conference is typically either run by two organizations, or it be two previously-seperate conferences that have been combined. The latter may happen after two related conferences have each become sparsely attended.

Comment: I think the point about the IJCAI conferences (and probably the others) is that they take place under the aegis of multiple agencies or institutions, in that case universities worldwide. The edit to my comment destroyed that element.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I'm not sure that's accurate. Almost every academic conference – joint or not – will have session chairs and program chairs from various institutions. What makes IJCAI a joint conference is not that their session chairs hail from different schools – that's what makes it a [conference](https://www.etymonline.com/word/conference). But if I'm wrong about that, we can restore the original comment.

Comment: You've got me wondering now.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Indeed, I have checked the IJCAI website. It gives no impression that [the journal division](https://www.ijcai.org/aijd) is involved with the conference.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă - I've reopened the question, so feel free to leave an answer. If you want to copy the example from my comment (which seems like an easier one to pinpoint), feel free to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Any *joint* activity means it involves or is sponsored by two or more independent entities.  For example, militaries often have *joint* exercises with their allies, in order to improve coordination between the services.  Politicians might serve on *joint* committees that include members from different government bodies, to increase cooperation.

A *joint* conference is one either sponsored by two or more organizations, or in which members from two (or more) organizations are expected to participate.  For example, the IJCAI is a multinational conference organized by and involving academics from many countries around the world, and the JCLC ([Joint Conference of Librarians of Color](http://www.jclcinc.org/conference/2018/about/)) is sponsored by five independent organizations of librarians.

Joint conferences are often held to pool resources, share knowledge, and improve communication between professionals from each of the independent entities.